# rails 5 algolia search - filter results by user status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, algolia

I'm trying to filter search results displayed using the algolia gem depending on whether the current user carries 'admin' status or not.

All users can create customers, but 'admin' users have access to all Customers regardless of whether they were created by that user. I am also using the devise gem for my 'users' model.

Customers controller:

```
def index
  if current_user.admin
    @customers = Customer.all.order(id: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  else
    @customers = Customer.where(user: current_user).order(id: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end
end
```

I am using the algolia rails gem to search by customers in customers#index

Search JS:

```
<!-- Algolia search JS -->
<script>
  var client = algoliasearch('x', 'x');
  var index = client.initIndex('Customer');
  //initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
  autocomplete('#aa-search-input',
{ hint: false }, {
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5}),
  //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
  displayKey: 'name',
  //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
  templates: {
      //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
      suggestion: function(suggestion) {
        return `<span>${suggestion.first_name.value}"</span>` +;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

What I need to do is filter the autocomplete suggestions depending on whether the logged on user is an 'admin' user or not. This needs to only filter the index for that particular session so that multiple users logged on simultaneously don't affect the customer index available to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! solution was as follows:
I created a 'user_id' record in my ‘Customer’ index:

**Customer.rb**

```
attribute :user_id do
  user.id if user
end
```

I then used the SrcParams.filter to filter results based on the user_id:

**JS file**

```
var client = algoliasearch('x', 'x');
var index = client.initIndex('Customer');
let admin = document.getElementById("admin-field").innerText; // returns "true" for admins
let userId = parseInt(document.getElementById("id-field").innerText); // returns the integer value of the user's id

var srcParams = { hitsPerPage: 5}

// conditionally set filter based on admin
if (admin != "true") {
  srcParams.filters = `user_id=${userId}`;
}

autocomplete('#aa-search-input', {
  hint: false
}, {
  // use the srcParams
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, srcParams),
   displayKey: 'name',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
    console.log(srcParams);
    return  `<span>${suggestion.first_name.value}"</span>` ;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, Algolia is not a relational database.

It does not know which `user has_many customers`, or that a `customer belongs_to user`. It also has no knowledge of Devise and that a user is an admin.

To replicate this relationship in Algolia you have to create a "flat object" that holds the relationship in an attribute.

For example, your "Customer" index could have records where an attribute lists who can view them.  You can call it `viewable_by` or `user_ids`, anything you want (if you do not have a "User" index, then these could be the `id` from your database, whatever works):

```
// sample Customer record in Algolia
{
    "name": "Ricky Bobby",
    "viewable_by": [1, 55, 278]
}
```

Next, I'll rely on you to pass your `current_user.admin` (true/false) and user `id` from Rails so that you can reference it in a JS conditional.

Then in autocomplete you create a conditional set of params.  If `current_user.admin` is `false` then filter on the user `id`:

```js
<!-- Algolia search JS -->
<
script >
  var client = algoliasearch('BFBCTI275G', '5818cd87afb6c0ef5e4d5ec4ed6580d0');
var index = client.initIndex('Customer');

// create variable
var srcParams = {
  hitsPerPage: 5
}

// conditionally set filter based on admin
// your job to get admin boolean and user id into JS
if (!current_user.admin) {
  srcParams.filters = 'viewable_by: current_user.id';
}

autocomplete('#aa-search-input', {
  hint: false
}, {
  // use the srcParams
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, srcParams),
  displayKey: 'name',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
      return `<span>${suggestion.first_name.value}"</span>` + ;
    }
  }
}); <
/script>
```

Comment: can't get this to work using your solution above, see my response on algolia: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/dynamic-filtering-based-on-current-user/6194/2

Comment: Awesome that you saw you were actually passing a string, and you needed to string interpolate the user id variable!

`srcParams.filters = `user_id=${userId}`;`

Comment: Thanks! Yes didn't realise at first that we could interpolate in the filter